# How would I declare a grammar rule for a number of tags in any order?

Tags: grammar, bison

I am trying to write a compiler for a formating language.This language has a start and an end property and a set of document and text properties. 
The first is just info for the document itself where as the second is the actual document (titles, paragraphs, lists... the usual). The first set must always follow the start property and must contain all properties BUT in any order the user might like.

Assuming that my tokens for the properites are PROP1, PROP2, PROP3 and PROP4 I can use recursion and an OR for all the properties so that the user can define any document property he wants.

```
doc_properties
    : /* empty */
    : doc_properties property  
    ;
property
    : PROP1
    : PROP2
    : PROP3
    : PROP4
    ;
```

BUT how do I make him to define them all and only once. One way that I thought (the easy and crude way I would like to avoid) is because I only have 4 document properties I can just make an or of all possible combinations. I am pretty sure there is another way. Any help?

My grammar so far is pretty simple and small

```
%{ /* C Stuff */ %}

/* union and error stuff and tokens */

%%

source
    : /* empty */  
    | entry_point doc_properties txt_properties exit_point
    ;

entry_point
    : SLASH BLOCK_S LBRACE DOC RBRACE 
    ;

doc_properties 
    : /* This is where my question goes */  
    ;

txt_properties
    : /* empty */  
    ;

exit_point
    : SLASH BLOCK_E LBRACE DOC RBRACE
    ;


%%

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* various checks for the arguments and the input output files */

        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        yyout = fopen(fn, "w");     
        //do{
            yyparse();
        //}while(!feof(yyin));
        fclose(yyin);
        fclose(yyout);

    return 0;
}

void yyerror(const char* str) {
    fprintf(stderr,"syntax error[%d]: %s\n",yylineno, str);
}
```

Also on an unrelated note does using yyparse() inside a do-while loop or just once by itself has any difference? Because I see it both ways and while the do-while loop makes more sense to me (because it requests a token parses and then again) I am not sure if the function repeats itself or something...

Comment: You could consider using ANTLR http://antlr.org/ it might be more easy to use for you. Or maybe http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/ if  coding in Ocaml.

Comment: I suppose but then I would have to spend time to learn it and since this is for a course and a topic I am not much interested it would be wasted time. Besides I am pretty sure that I have to use flex and bison since this is what we were instructed to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a number of syntax rules that are best enforced by semantic checks rather than by the grammar itself.  For instance, in C like languages, the `break` construct can only appear inside loops (and switch), yet it is far simpler to accept it like any regular statement, and *later*, in the semantic analysis pass, reject invalid uses to `break`.

You could use a similar pattern: accept any combination of `PROP`, and later reject those that do not respect your constraints.  Of course, you can also do this while parsing, using `YYERROR` to raise an error when appropriate.

Wrt to your second question, `yyparse` is to be called only once, but then of course it is in charge of calling the scanner (`yylex`) repeatedly.  Note that Bison offers "push-parsers", where *you* are in charge of calling `yylex` repeatedly, and pass its results to `yyparse` (repeatedly too).  See http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Push-Decl for more details.

Comment: thanks for the info... so basically what you are saying is that i should do the recursion and then check the final result if it conforms to what i want... can i check what tokens it has returned though, something like for-each $i { switch($i) PROP1:... PROP2:... etc}

Comment: I will just add a non-terminal for each tag and each time one is recognized I will increase corresponding counter, so at the end I can check for those that have an upper or lower limit